# What is the difference between JavaScript forEach loop that uses Synchronous and Asynchronous versions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

I came across this JavaScript library on GitHub:

**JavaScript Sync/Async forEach** - An optionally-asynchronous forEach with an interesting interface. https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-sync-async-foreach

I am a bit confused on what it does exactly though as far as comparing the ASYNC forEach functionality and the standard Synchronous forEach JS.

---

### forEach.js Library Code

```
/*!
 * Sync/Async forEach
 * https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-sync-async-foreach
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */

(function(exports) {

  // Iterate synchronously or asynchronously.
  exports.forEach = function(arr, eachFn, doneFn) {
    var i = -1;
    // Resolve array length to a valid (ToUint32) number.
    var len = arr.length >>> 0;

    // This IIFE is called once now, and then again, by name, for each loop
    // iteration.
    (function next(result) {
      // This flag will be set to true if `this.async` is called inside the
      // eachFn` callback.
      var async;
      // Was false returned from the `eachFn` callback or passed to the
      // `this.async` done function?
      var abort = result === false;

      // Increment counter variable and skip any indices that don't exist. This
      // allows sparse arrays to be iterated.
      do { ++i; } while (!(i in arr) && i !== len);

      // Exit if result passed to `this.async` done function or returned from
      // the `eachFn` callback was false, or when done iterating.
      if (abort || i === len) {
        // If a `doneFn` callback was specified, invoke that now. Pass in a
        // boolean value representing "not aborted" state along with the array.
        if (doneFn) {
          doneFn(!abort, arr);
        }
        return;
      }

      // Invoke the `eachFn` callback, setting `this` inside the callback to a
      // custom object that contains one method, and passing in the array item,
      // index, and the array.
      result = eachFn.call({
        // If `this.async` is called inside the `eachFn` callback, set the async
        // flag and return a function that can be used to continue iterating.
        async: function() {
          async = true;
          return next;
        }
      }, arr[i], i, arr);

      // If the async flag wasn't set, continue by calling `next` synchronously,
      // passing in the result of the `eachFn` callback.
      if (!async) {
        next(result);
      }
    }());
  };

}(typeof exports === "object" && exports || this));
```

---

### Demos

Looking at 2 of the demos on there GitHub repo it shows that the console output is exactly the same for the Async and Synchronous versions...

```
// Generic "done" callback.
function allDone(notAborted, arr) {
  console.log("done", notAborted, arr);
}
```

### Synchronous Demo

```
forEach(["a", "b", "c"], function(item, index, arr) {
  console.log("each", item, index, arr);
}, allDone);
// logs:
// each a 0 ["a", "b", "c"]
// each b 1 ["a", "b", "c"]
// each c 2 ["a", "b", "c"]
// done true ["a", "b", "c"]
```

### Asynchronous Demo

```
forEach(["a", "b", "c"], function(item, index, arr) {
  console.log("each", item, index, arr);
  var done = this.async();
  setTimeout(function() {
    done();
  }, 500);
}, allDone);
// logs:
// each a 0 ["a", "b", "c"]
// each b 1 ["a", "b", "c"]
// each c 2 ["a", "b", "c"]
// done true ["a", "b", "c"]
```

---

There are several other demos on the repo here https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-sync-async-foreach

---

### What is the difference between the 2 when it comes to real world usage?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, what "real world usage" means here. Certainly you can see that they are doing different things?

Comment: @Bergi you mean the only difference is the Asynchronous version delays each loop by 500ms is the only real difference or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole idea. And asynchronous functions of all kinds are quite common in the real world as well, not just this artificial `setTimeout` example.

Comment: @Bergi couldn't I simply add a 500ms timeout in the Synchronous versions loop though to have the same result?

Comment: No, you cannot, timeouts are asynchronous. Have you tried it? Do you know how asynchrony works in JS?

Comment: @JasonDavis, `forEach.js` is not asynchronous by itself, it is a helper that allows you to execute asynchronous code then continue array iteration on callback. Classic forEach is good for blocking iterations, as there is no easy way (or no way AFAIC) to execute asynchronous code (classic forEach waits for a function to return). setTimeout() here is just an example of something asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi thanks I wasn't aware

Comment: @KubaWyrostek thanks it makes more sense now

Comment: both are methods provided by the script, it's not a "js forEach"